# Replicate paragraph text using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a paragrah that I need to replicate dynamically. How do I do this in jQuery? Here is example code:

```
<p class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
```

The paragraph needs to be copied to another part of the page that will look like this:

```
<p id=print-info> jQuery inserted paragraph text </p>
```

I have thought of using the `.attr()` method but not sure how to go about doing that for paragraph text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this line, as seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NTEmR/)

```
$('#print-info').html($('.info:first').html());​
```